# How to create a 'Close' button to hide the current view in Sencha T2?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Starting off with my `Main` view, it loads another view with xytpe 'homepanel'.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
    alias: 'widget.main',
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'homepanel', // loads view with xytpe 'homepanel'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

from 'homepanel' we can go to the `Youtube` view which has a `Close` button in the top left

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.YoutubeView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'youtube',
    // id:    'youtube',
    config: {
        navigationBar: {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype:    'button',
                    iconMask: true,
                    text:     'Close',
                    align:    'left',
                    action:   'closeButton'
                }
            ]
        },
    }
});
```

When clicking the `Close` button, I'd like to go back to the `Main` view, if possible reloading it in case new posts have been placed.

Unfotunately this controlller code doesn't work as it throws a `Object ext-viewport has no method 'hide'` error.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.PostStuffController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
        'Ext.navigation.View'
    ],
    config: {
        control: {
            'button[action=closeButton]': {
                tap: 'tapClose'
            }
        }
    },
    tapClose: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.getId().hide();
    }
});
```

Any suggestion on how to close the current view and load `Main`?

Comment: How do you go from the homepanel to the YouTube panel ? Because you justo need to do the opposite here... Right ?

Comment: yes... but I'd like a solution that applies to not only the Youtube page, but others one might navigate to - on homepanel, I have a navigation bar with a button that opens an overlay -- then one chooses Youtube, text, etc -- didn't post that b/c post would be too large - but let me know if you'd like to see the code

Comment: @TDeBailleul your suggestion makes sense and it works - I had the `Cancel` button take me back to `xtype: homepanel` which is a list with blog posts, linked to a controller to push a view with the full post -- but when I go back from `Youtube` to `homepanel`, no clicks (taps) are firing on homepanel -- any ideas?

Comment: If the application is not too big I'd suggest you create a [senchafiddle](http://www.senchafiddle.com). If you do I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
tapClose: function (cmp) {
    Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems.

1. YoutubeView extends a navigation view.  Normally you'd have a main view which extends a navigation view and then push and pop views from this main view.
2. Don't use id's.  This is the cause of the taps not firing the second time.

Comment: dave I've been avoiding `id`s all along and there aren't any (at least that I've coded in there) -- my `main view` extends a tabpanel, and contains `xtype: homepanel` -- which extends a navigation view -- from here one goes to `youtube view` which as you pointed out should be pushed/popped and not extend - let me know if I understood correctly

Comment: sorry dave that is not in my current code (which is still not working) -- I left it in OP by mistake

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.PostStuffController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
requires: [
    'Ext.navigation.View'
],
config: {
    control: {
        'button[action=closeButton]': {
            tap: 'tapClose'
        }
    }
},


tapClose: function (button, e, options) {
   button.up('navigationview').push({
   xtype: 'main', // view which you want to push
 });
}

});
```

Comment: this gives me `'Uncaught TypeError: Object ext-viewport has no method 'hide''`

Comment: @torr can you try putting hide : function () above tapClose : function()

Comment: @torr i have edited once more,this time i am pushing the view with navigation bar. Give it a try.

Comment: vikal that works but 2 issues - [1] the pushed panel has an additional navigation bar on top; [2] the taps are still not firing on the pushed view -